# Assign rank to numbers in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to be able to assign a rank to numbers in a vector depending on their size and make a new vector containing these ranks.

For instance, if I have the vector `[5, 2, 3, 1]`, I want to return `[4, 2, 3, 1]` (as 5 is the largest number and 1 is the smallest). Equal numbers should share an average rank preferably (for instance, if both are the same and are the lowest, they should get an average rank of 1.5).

How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Comment: How is what you return related to the input? Can you make a more clear example or elaborate some more. Thanks

Comment: It's the position of the number if the input were sorted

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Exactly what n00dle just said.

Comment: Note that if a number occurs more than once, it will have 2 different rankings by that definition.

Comment: That's an interesting point. I hadn't thought of that. @rbm how would you want to handle that situation?

Comment: @n00dle I would want two equal numbers to share an average rank preferably, as I am using this for a statistical test which works in that way. So for instance if both are the same and are the lowest they should both get 1.5. Sorry that I didn't mention this beforehand.

Comment: Ah, currently neither of the given answers do that. I'll look into it.

Comment: @n00dle That'd be great, thanks a lot!

Comment: I had no idea how I did not notice that. I guess it was because the example vectors were identical aside from the 4 and 5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of sorting, I suggest you use `unique`:

```
[~, ~, ranking] = unique(x);
```

It also sorts the vector but maps identical values to the same index. This way identical elements in the original vector get the same rank. For instance, if `x = [5 2 3 1 3]`, we get:

```
ranking =
   4   2   3   1   3
```

If you want an "average" rank, you could use `accumarray` in combination with the information obtained both from `unique` and from `sort`, so do the following instead:

```
[~, ~, idx_u] = unique(x);
[~, idx_s] = sort(x);
mean_ranks = accumarray(idx_u(:), idx_s(idx_s), [], @mean);
ranking = mean_ranks(idx_u);
```

In our example we would get:

```
ranking =
   1.0000
   2.0000
   3.5000
   5.0000
   3.5000
```

Note that both values 3 got the average rank of 3.5, as they shared ranks 3 and 4.

Comment: @EitanT Nice answer, thanks for your help! However, I forgot to mention that beforehand, but I want two equal numbers to be assigned an average rank, i.e. if two numbers are the smallest of the array for instance, they should both get rank 1.5.

Comment: @rbm Please take a look at the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second output param of [`sort()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) to do what you want.

e.g. (tested in Matlab 2011b)

```
>> [~,ranking] = sort([5 2 3 1]);
>> ranking
ranking =
     4     2     3     1
```

**EDIT:** (The OP asked for further explanation)

From your example, I determined that higher ranks go to larger numbers, so it's essentially the position of the value if the list was sorted.

Calling `sort( )` sorts the list into ascending order. The sorted list is the first thing returned. I put a `~` there as we don't really care about the sorted list, so we just throw the value away.

The second output param of `sort` is the mapping of the unsorted list onto the sorted one. That is, for each item in the unsorted list, it gives its position in the sorted one.

**Edit Again:**
It sounds like you want "[Fractional Ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Fractional_ranking_.28.221_2.5_2.5_4.22_ranking.29)" from your description. There's nothing built into Matlab as far as I can see that does this directly, but there are files on the FEX. I've never used them, but there's one with a comprehensive description, so it seems likely to be a good bet: [Rankings - File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19496-rankings)

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate a bit on why this works? Did you define ranking beforehand? Or is that a predefined function?

Comment: I've updated my answer - please let me know if it's clear and if not I'll try again

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't aware of the fact that the sort function has two output arguments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The 2nd output of sort DOES NOT give the rank, rather it gives the indices when passed to the original input, it would give the sorted version. This is very easy to get confused, consider: x =  [100    50    20    40], [~,ind] = sort(x) gives  ind = [3     4     2     1]. This is NOT the ranking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Statistics and Machine learning toolbox, then you can use the Matlab built-in function [`tiedrank`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/tiedrank.html):

```
>> ranking = tiedrank([5 2 3 1 3]);
>> ranking

ranking =

    5.0000    2.0000    3.5000    1.0000    3.5000
```