# Sorting data in MATLAB dependant on one column

Tags: matlab, sorting

How do I sort a column based on the values in another column in MATLAB?

Column `A` shows position data (it is neither ascending or descending in order) Column `B` contains another column of position data. Finally column `C` contains numerical values. Is it possible to link the first position value in `B` with its numerical value in the first cell of `C`? Then after this I want to sort `B` such that it is in the same order as column `A` with the `C` values following their `B` counterparts?The length of my columns would be 1558 values.

Before case;

```
A     B     C
1      4      10
4      1      20
3      5      30
5      2      40
2      3      50
```

After Case;

```
A     B     C
1      1      20
4      4      10
3      3      50
5      5      30
2      2      40
```

Basically `A` and `B` became the same and Column `C` followed `B`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't want things necessarily in ascending or descending order, I don't think any built-in sorting functions like `sortrows()` will help here. Instead you are matching elements in one column with elements in another column.

Using `[~,idx]=ismember(A,B)` will tell you where each element of B is in A. You can use that to sort the desired columns.

```
M=[1      4      10
   4      1      20
   3      5      30
   5      2      40
   2      3      50];
A=M(:,1); B=M(:,2); C=M(:,3);
[~,idx]=ismember(A,B); 

sorted_matrix = [A B(idx) C(idx)]
```

Comment: Nice use of `ismember` I forgot that it also returns locations.  Good solution because of all the error handling that it does.

Comment: How do I implement this if some of the values in column A are negative

Comment: @Jerry Your comment helped me catch an error in the original solution. It's fixed now and should work even with negative entries in A (assuming there are corresponding negative entries in B).

Comment: @Geoff I'm still getting the same error when I use ``%Create matrix%
Matrix = [Control, LES2_54_pos, LES2_54_U];
%Sort Matrix%
A=Matrix(:,1); B=Matrix(:,2); C=Matrix(:,3);
[~,idx]=ismember(A,B); 

sorted_matrix = [A B(idx) C(idx)]`` I'm not sure if its relevant but the negative values in A dont match to negative values in B before the sorting. Hence why the sorting is required.

Comment: @Geoff ``Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in Sort_data (line 17)
sorted_matrix = [A B(idx) C(idx)]``

Comment: If the matrix is layed out like the following ``>> M=[-1      4      10
   4      1      20
   -3      -5      30
   5      -2      40
   2      3      50];
A=M(:,1); B=M(:,2); C=M(:,3);
[~,idx]=ismember(A,B); 

sorted_matrix = [A B(idx) C(idx)]
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`` the error can be reproduced. The negatives do no match up in both columns

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear by your previous comment that the negatives may appear in one column but not the other. This is crucial since `idx=0` whenever there isn't an exact match. To alleviate this try `[~,idx]=ismember(abs(A),abs(B))` . For more general examples this could be dangerous if you have, e.g., -1 and 1 both show up in the same column.

Comment: @Jerry So, what must be the output for `M=[-1 4 10 4 1 20 -3 -5 30 5 -2 40 2 3 50]`? Edit your question with such a case?

Comment: Part of both columns A and B do have an overlap i.e. 70 and -70 etc Is there any other way around this?

Comment: @Jerry Please edit the original post with a new matrix `M` and the desired corresponding result so that it is clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @Jerry I'm confused as well. I thought `A` and `B` had identical elements, just in different orders. This isn't the case for this new matrix. Please clarify.

Comment: @Geoff I think I figured it out. Try `[~,idx]=ismember(abs(A),abs(B))` on the new matrix.

Comment: @beaker nice! but I guess you missed my second to last comment :)

Comment: Ha! I did... got caught up in trying to reconcile the numbers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Given `M = [A B C]`:

```
M =

    1    4   10
    4    1   20
    3    5   30
    5    2   40
    2    3   50
```

You need to sort the rows of the matrix **excluding** the first column:

```
s = sortrows(M(:,2:3));

s =

    1   20
    2   40
    3   50
    4   10
    5   30
```

Then use the first column as the indices to reorder the resulting submatrix:

```
s(M(:,1),:);

ans =

    1   20
    4   10
    3   50
    5   30
    2   40
```

This would be used to build the output matrix:

```
N = [M(:,1) s(M(:,1),:)];

N =

    1    1   20
    4    4   10
    3    3   50
    5    5   30
    2    2   40
```

---

The previous technique will obviously only work if `A` and `B` are permutations of the values `(1..m)`. If this is not the case, then we need to find the **ranking** of each value in the array. Let's start with new values for our arrays:

```
    A    B   C
    1    5   60
    6    1   80
    9    6   60
   -4    9   40
    5   -4   30
```

We construct `s` as before:

```
s = sortrows([B C]);

s =

   -4   30
    1   80
    5   60
    6   60
    9   40
```

We can generate the rankings one of two ways. If the elements of `A` (and `B`) are unique, we can use the third output of `unique` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746759/assign-rank-to-numbers-in-a-vector):

```
[~, ~, r] = unique(A);

r =

   2
   4
   5
   1
   3
```

If the values of `A` are **not** unique, we can use the second return value of sort, the indices in the original array of the elements in sorted order, to generate the rank of each element:

```
[~, r] = sort(A);

r =

   4
   1
   5
   2
   3

[~, r] = sort(r);

r =

   2
   4
   5
   1
   3
```

As you can see, the resulting `r` is the same, it just takes 2 calls to `sort` rather than 1 to `unique`. We then use `r` as the list of indices for `s` above:

```
M = [A s(r, :)];

M =

    1    1   80
    6    6   60
    9    9   40
   -4   -4   30
    5    5   60
```

Comment: How could I implement this if some of the numbers in column A are negative?

Answer (score 1):

Powerful combo of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`matrix-multiplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058139/why-is-matlab-so-fast-in-matrix-multiplication) solves it and good for `code-golfing` too! Here's the implementation, assuming `M` as the input matrix -

```
[M(:,1) bsxfun(@eq,M(:,1),M(:,2).')*M(:,2:3)]
```

Sample run -

```
>> M
M =
     1     4    10
     4     1    20
     3     5    30
     5     2    40
     2     3    50
>> [M(:,1) bsxfun(@eq,M(:,1),M(:,2).')*M(:,2:3)]
ans =
     1     1    20
     4     4    10
     3     3    50
     5     5    30
     2     2    40
```

Comment: why have you included ``*M(:,2:3)`` when I use this code it orders the matrix but my original values are multiplied which now gives me incorrect values

Answer (score 0):

If you must retain the order of `A` then use something like this

```
matrix = [1 4 10; 4 1 20; 3 5 30; 5 2 40; 2 3 50];
idx = arrayfun(@(x) find(matrix(:,2) == x), matrix(:,1));
sorted = [matrix(:,1), matrix(idx,2:3)];
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain why I am getting the following error  Error using arrayfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Error in Sort_data (line 14)
idx = arrayfun(@(x) find(Matrix(:,2) == x), Matrix(:,1));

Comment: I would guess that happens because you have repeated values in column 2.  If that is true you need to determine which one to keep.  If the first, then change to `find(matrix(:,2) == x, 1, 'first')`.

Comment: @Jerry if you have repeated values for either column `A` or `B` you will have an unbalanced answer.  If there are repeated values in `B` this means you have at least 1 vacant `A` entry and the 3rd line will error.  Also you have at least 2 rows of `B` that will match to `A`.  Sounds like you need cleanup your numbers beforehand.  You can use `unique` with the `rows` option if all 3 columns are the same.  If they are not you need to use some selection criteria like max/min `C`